# Is there a more elegant IF solution than nesting duplicate formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Currently, I regularly write index match formulas that, if they pull an empty cell, pull a zero value. I then need to remove this from my results. I don't want to faff about with Find and Replace, and the data is as is, and can't be sanitised further. The formula currently looks like this.

```
=if(index(c2:c10,match(a2,B2:b10)=0,"",index(c2:c10,match(a2,B2:b10))
```

which is just downright ugly, and slow to boot. In addition, if I'm referencing more than one cell (i.e. doesn't find it in B:B, look in D:D, E:E etc) then this is doubled each time, leaving hugely unwieldy formula. I'm using MS Office Professional Plus 2016

Therefore, what I need to be able to do is to write a formula which, if the result is a specific value, it does something, else it pulls the result of the formula. This doesn't seem to exist anywhere I can find, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the cell need to be to contain "" or just appear blank?  Can you use formatting to hide the zeroes?

Something along the line of

`General;-General;` or `1.00;-1.00;`

Generally number before the first `;` gives formatting for positive number, before second `;` formatting for negative numbers and after second `;` gives formatting for 0.  If you leave this third one blank nothing will show in the cell although the value for any calculations or lookups will still be 0.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't exist.

The usual workaround is to use a (potentially hidden) helper column.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is all text values, you can wrap your formula in T(), this returns blank when it encounters 0 (or any other number, for that matter).